# VP8' Libvpx for android using JNI

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, vp8, libvpx

I want to use vp8 in my android application , that's why I download libvpx written with C++ , and now I want to connect it to my app with JNI. So the steps I have done

1. Place a libvpx checkout in the jni directory of my app
2. Run the configure script from the jni directory like this `./libvpx/configure --target=armv7-android-gcc --disable-examples --disable-neon --sdk-path=/opt/android-ndk-r6b/`
3. Place an Android.mk file in the jni directory that references the Android.mk file in the libvpx directory:

   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
       include $(CLEAR_VARS)
       include libvpx/build/make/Android.mk
4. make Makefile , that created after running configuration
5. creat Android new Builder as shown [here](http://pickerwengs.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-building-jni-source-code-in.html)
6. Debug , and it should build libvpx and include it in my project

But there are no any libvpx in my app.

Can somebody help me, give some suggestion or some good tutorial of libvpx for android?

Thanks, Regards

Comment: It's included in Android, "Android is WebM-enabled from version 2.3 - Gingerbread" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP8, you just need to refer to the official Android library in the codec section.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes Android is WebM-enabled from version 2.3 - Gingerbread. But can I use it , and if can ,than how?
Regards

Comment: the easiest and most compatible way is to code in Java with the MediaCodec class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html , this is the class of reference for the whole codec package, if you can't find something strictly related to the Vp8 just Google "Android MediaCodec _something_" and you are likely to find something useful.

Comment: Thank you very much , I'll check this , and please live your comment as an answer and I'll choose this if something ;)